# C++ Arithmetic Operator without new return object

Tags: c++

This is a rather simple concept. I have an arithmetic operator and I wish for the operation to *update* not *create* an object. Essentially,

```
MyType A;
MyType B;
MyType C;

A = B - C;
A = C - B;
```

The statement `A = B - C` should not call the constructor for MyType again since A is already created, i.e. the constructor should only be called 3 times in this program. Is there some way to achieve this while maintaining a nice syntax? I suspect that I could let the operator function know not to create an object but rather to use some reference. Is there a more streamlined way to do this using some c++ syntax unknown to me?

```
class MyType
{
    MyType* OperatorReturnObj;

    MyType operator-(const MyType& Left, const MyType& Right)
    {
        // This removed and replaced with SetOperatorReturnObj function
        // MyType OperatorReturnObj();

        OperatorReturnObj= Left - Right;
        return OperatorReturnObj;
    }


    void MyType SetOperatorReturnObj(MyType* Ref)
    {
         OperatorReturnObj = Ref;
    }
};
```

Comment: `MyType A();` is not even an object declaration - [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @LogicStuff - that's **not** the most vexing parse. It's a function declaration, pure and simple.

Comment: @Pete It must be like second time I said that :)

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

Comment: @D Drmmr  I had though of that kind of approach but it seems more complicated than its worth for this case. It doesn't make sense to add that much code simplify syntax as subtly as it would in the end. Nice method though!

Comment: You will still have a temporary object created with expression templates. What you gain is that in case you have A = B + C + D + E, you will have only one temporary object instead of 3.

Comment: @axxis: The trick is that the temporary object is lightweight, and is only materialized when assigning to A.

Comment: @RussellTrahan: Can you live with _move assignment_ ? `MyType::operator=(MyType&&)` can steal the guts of the temporary `B+C`.

Comment: A slightly vexing parse imo

Comment: @RussellTrahan did you mean `MyType A,B,C;` ? Your current code attempts to subtract function pointers and so on.

Comment: MyType A(); calls the constructor, in reality there are parameters so MyType A(param); is the same as MyType A = MyType(param). I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Without ugly tricks like creating pool of objects and using them internally (where complications would be more expensive than any benefits for this case), there is no way to achieve this. Problem is that statement:

```
A = B - C;
```

is equal to:

```
A.operator=( operator-( B, C ) );
```

as you can see `operator-( B, C )` has to be executed first and provide result somewhere. So you either have to change syntax like:

```
A += B; A -= C; // or even
(A += B) -= C; // or maybe
A += B -= C;
```

or use regular syntax and if you need efficiency implement move semantics.

After some thought you can create object of type `MyTypeExression` which does not do actual calculations but remember arguments and operations and only do them later when `MyType::operator=(MyTypeExression)` is executed. Though for that to work you probably need a wrapper with smart pointer for `MyType` so `MyTypeExression` does not have to copy it's arguments. So this solution can be considered as complicated trick I mentioned before.

Comment: A += B; A -= C;  is what I'm currently using. I was hoping for the possibility of passing a third arguement to the operator function such as `operator-(B,C, Result)` in some way.

Comment: You cannot change argument count for operators, you can though create a method or standalone function that does it.

Comment: Yeah, obviously I could make a function `void Subtract(MyType& Left, MyType& Right, Mytype& Result)` to do this, but I lose the syntax appeal.

Answer (score 2):

> I wish for the operation to update not create an object

For `A = B - C;`, `A` will be **updated**, by `operator=`.

More particular, `operator-` 's return value is passed by value, a temporary variable has to be created inside `operator-` and then copied/moved to `A`.

BTW1: `OperatorReturnObj= Left - Right;` will cause an infinite recursion.

BTW2: `MyType A();` is a function declaration indeed. [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: I think the question is asking how to avoid that temporary

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

In A = B - C, first the B - C expression is evaluated. Then the result is copied to A.
The B - C expression knows nothing about A, so it is not possible to update A directly.
You can overload the assignment operator but this will not prevent the creation of a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

First of all, you didn't specified how to initialize the internal pointer attribute, so at this moment it points to an unspecified value in the memory stack.

Second, the `operator-` **method**(!) isn't defined like you did. [look at "binary arithmetic operators"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)
binary operators have to return a reference to the object they are called from.

Third, the object itself is passed *"automagically"* to its methods, and its available as the `this` pointer.
So you **don't** have to pass it as the first parameter.
Finally, to return a reference you have to return the value, and not the pointer : --> `*this`.

So an expression like `A=B+C` is evaluated to:

```
A.operator=(B.operator+(C))
```

So B+C is different than C+B. (I don't enter in the details of inheritance here..)

Inspired from [the same previous link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) above:

```
class X {
    int internalprivatevalue;
    //.... 
public:
    X& operator+(const X& second) {
        // actual addition of second to *this takes place here
        // e.g. internalprivatevalue+=second. internalprivatevalue;
        return *this; // return the result by reference!! 
    }
```

}

Hope to have clarified a little more your doubts.